# running maven scanner throws a JAXBException

Tags: java-8, maven-3

With SonarQube 6.5, jdk 1.8.0_144 and sonar.maven.plugin 3.3.0.603, running `mvn sonar:sonar` gives me the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project tdd: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

What am i missing?

Thanks,

Nilesh

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today as well. I recently installed JDK 9.0.1 and had switched the language level of my project over to source and target version 1.9. Executing a clean install triggered this exception. The issue was fixed and released recently [in issue 2506 of their JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2506), so updating the sonarjava plugin from the sonarqube instance's administation panel fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same exact problem while running sonar analysis with `java-9`.

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: D:\java\maven\3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\java\jdk\1.9.0_181
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
...
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) @ _test ---
...
[INFO] SonarQube version: 6.5.0
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project
maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

Same build still works fine with `java-8`.

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: D:\java\maven\3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\java\jdk\1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
...
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) @ _test ---
...
[INFO] SonarQube version: 6.5.0
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

I see same behavior with `javax.javaee-api 6.0 7.0` or `8.0` thus problem seems to be not related to project dependencies.

Older `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.sonar-maven-plugin` `3.2` version of plugin produces same result thus problem is not related to newer `3.3.0.603` plugin version.

Run only with `maven 3.5.0`.

Just for sake of it successfully tested with `1.8.0_144` in addition to `1.8.0_131`.

Exact version of SonarQube is `6.5.0.27846`.

Just a suggestion: make sure you are actually running `java-8`.

`mvn -v`